# Сохранение содержимого QTableWidget в файл.

Tags: qt, c++

Можно ли каким-либо способом, кроме записи в файл содержимого ячеек по одной, сохранить содержимое QtableWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные вы из какой-то модели берете? Если так, то попробуйте перевести модель в [QVariant](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qvariant.html), потом можно перевести, к примеру, в [QByteArray](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qbytearray.html) и записать в файл.

Наверняка есть способы проще, но это первое что в голову пришло.

Comment: Как вариант. Попробую. Но, как я уже понял, сохранить содержимое в практически одно действие (как например с `QTextEdit`) не получится.

Comment: Ну, в QTableWidget'е же не один объект хранится, в отличие от QTextEdit'а.